# Trouble with vertical divider in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hi i use horizontal RecyclerView. But except horizontal devider i need vertical devider in each Item (different height).

I try

```
<View
    android:layout_width="3dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

This work then i set ***android:layout_height="50dp"***. But with ***android:layout_height="wrap_content"*** View it's gone.

I try get height from adapter

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ClubListViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.parent.getHeight();
 }
```

Method return -1

How solve this trouble?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:layout_height="match_parent"` instead, place the view in ViewHolder layout. Then its height will be the same as item's height.

Comment: I use android:layout_height="match_parent" and put View in Viewolder, but  not work.